# fluent nhibernate not supported exception newexpression

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to nhibernate and  I'm finding it quite hard to really get comfortable with it. I have this query:

```
        var results2 = (from purchase in _session.Query<Purchase>()
                        group purchase by new { purchase.symbol } into purchases
                        select new Quote()
                        {
                            shares= purchases.Sum(p => p.shares)
                        }).ToList();
```

but I get notsupportedexception and the error message is just newexpression.

Comment: Group by has limited support currently in Linq2NH. I know for a fact it currently doesn't support multiple column group by clauses. I can't remember how it supports single column group by clauses

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the question's date, I guess that question was about NHibernate pre-3.2.

Assuming that your `Quote` is a simple POCO class and you use NHibernate 3.2 or later, this query works fine - see [my blog post](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2013/04/nhibernate-linq-groupby-capabilities.html) for some details about `GroupBy` capabilities in NHibernate.

So the solution simply is to upgrade.